# Angular unit tests: check constant value

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm writing my first unit tests for my first Angular application so I have many questions.

In one of the test I want to check that IP address of the backend server is defined with constant function.

Here is a declaration:

```
var orderApp = angular.module('orderApp', ['ngRoute', '720kb.datepicker']);

orderApp.constant('config', {
    apiUrl:'http://192.192.192.192:6673'
});
```

Here is a test file:

```
'use strict';

describe("Order Table page", function(){

    beforeEach(module('orderApp'));

    it('Server IP should be defined', function(){
        expect(orderApp.config.apiUrl).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

orderApp variable is undefined and I receive error. How to reference module object? Or are there any better ways to check declaration of constants?

Comment: I'm not sure there is much of a point in 'unit testing' a constant. But if you were to do that I believe you would need to inject the constant into a test controller to check against. At least that's the way you would actually use the constant in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting the `config` constant:

```
'use strict';

describe("Order Table page", function(){
    var testee;

    beforeEach(module('orderApp'));

    beforeEach(inject('config') {
        testee = config;
    });

    it('Server IP should be defined', function(){
        expect(testee.apiUrl).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```